# How can I get the correct Date format with vue3-datepicker?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, datepicker, vue-component, vuejs3

I Can't figure out how to change this date (Thu Nov 24 2022 16:13:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time) to (Thu Nov 24). Also the datepicker timepicker returns the value in json string ({ "hours": 16, "minutes": 14, "seconds": 0 }) instead of 16:14.

This is the datepicker, in the input box it shows the correct format

```
<Datepicker
 v-model="workout.date"
 inputformat="dd/MM/YYYY"
 Datepicker
/>
```

This is the timepicker, also showing correct format when entering

```
<Datepicker v-model="workout.startTime" timePicker />
```

This is the script

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Workout } from '@/model/workout';
import { useWorkoutsStore } from '@/stores/workoutsStore';
import { ref, Ref } from 'vue';
import WorkoutList from '@/components/WorkoutList.vue';
import Datepicker from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker';

import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

const workout: Ref<Workout> = ref({
  name: '',
  trainer: '',
  description: '',
  location: '',
  date: '',
  startTime: '',
  endTime: '',
});
const { addWorkout } = useWorkoutsStore();

const router = useRouter();

const submitForm = () => {
  addWorkout({ ...workout.value });
  workout.value.name = '';
  workout.value.trainer = '';
  workout.value.description = '';
  workout.value.location = '';
  workout.value.startTime = '';
  workout.value.endTime = '';
  router.push({ name: 'Workouts' });
};
</script>
```

`But when the dates get to DataTable, then they are in the wrong formats (as mentioned above).`

```
<DataTable :value="workouts">
  <Column field="date" header="Kuupäev" />
  <Column field="startTime" header="Algus" />
</DataTable>
```

Comment: You haven't stated which DataTable  plugin do you use. I guess, you will need to format the date/time in the date/time column of the DataTable plugin.

Comment: Please consider to provide minimal working sample containing source code with  Datepicker and DataTable only.  This will help us to understand your code better. The best way is to create a sandbox with your solution which we could fix for you.